# Create empty matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

So, is there a way to achieve the same thing in python as the following line in R:
matrix( rep(NA, 3*5), ncol = 5 )

To be more specific, do I need to define an array before reference it in python? How is this process different from MATLAB? I tried to create an array full of 0 using np.zeros((5, 3)), but is there a way to create an empty one and simply keep adding numbers into it?

Comment: This *variable-initialization (or allocation)* is something simpy not performed in python. The matrix full of zeros is as close to empty you will get. Also the **exact** same question exists here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347559/create-empty-matrix-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

An array full of 0 using `np.zeros((5, 3))` is the best thing you can do here because, there no such thing as "variable declaration" or "variable initialization" in Python.

See this answer: [Python variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11008311/1952350)