# Why changing an element of a matrix is changing both rows?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following code.

```
x = [['']*2]*2 # [['', ''], ['', '']]
x[0][0] = 'a'
```

This produces the following. But why? When I actually just changed the first element of the first list.

```
[['a', ''], ['a', '']]
```

Or is `[['']*cols]*rows` not the right way to create a matrix in Python?

Comment: Are you really using Python 2?

Comment: Yes, I am using Python 2.

Comment: I’m curious, is it for any particular reason?

Comment: the inner * is ok since replicates an immutable string. But the outer * replicates a reference to a mutable list. When you change one, you change both.  It's a repeat without copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python is using the same list twice and just referencing it.

You can use the function copy() for creating copies or use numpy for creating empty matrix (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347614/1223945)

Comment: Ah OK. I think I can use a list comprehension or a map function then.

Comment: I ended up using list(map(lambda row: [None] * cols, [None] * rows))

Comment: Yes you can. You can also use Numpy

Comment: @MetallicPriest if my answer helped with your question, please mark it as the correct answer.